# When creating an order programmatically how to set different product image

Tags: orders, shopping-cart

I'm trying to create order programmatically. But I cannot set a different product image for that order. Here this order image will be send from mobile application. Thats why I need to set different product image without using default one.

```
protected function _addProductToCart($productId, $qty, $imagePath)
{        
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $cart =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); 
    $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
    $cart->save();
    $quote = $cart->getQuote();      
    $quote->setIsTemplate(1);
    $quote->save();

    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote->getId());     
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
      $item->setTemplateImage($imagePath);
      $item->save();
    }
    $quote->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    $session->setCartWasUpdated(true);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to set product image? That is not something that is set on an order item directly. Do you mean that the product image is not displaying in the cart where as it is when you add a product normally from the web interface?

Comment: @RobertEgginton I need to add different image there. Its not similar to currently loaded product image by id

Comment: If you are trying to have different image every time you create an order, instead of changing the product image, use custom options. They will retain with the order even after product itself is deleted/modified.

Comment: @Prateek I need to show that image in shopping cart. Thats why I need to change it. Can custom options selected when displaying cart image?

Comment: By default ? No, but you can create some code to achieve that, it shouldn't be hard and many questions are here already on SE for that.